# Rails 3 and Ajax/JSON/JQuery/ Direct DOM Update - used with Scaffold Program

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jsonp

I wish to modify a the outputs of a scaffold generated program. Basically, I need to modify the generated views and controllers to:

1. Send Ajax requests from the HTML form to the controller for processing basic CRUD actions - Create, Update,Destroy,Edit and perhaps Index.
2. Respond to the HTML form using JSON.
3. Update the form inplace ( no refresh ) in the browser through direct DOM manipulation using the JSON data.
4. Use JSONP to communicate with a Website (e.g. Amazon ) and display book details on screen.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a Q and A site ... you need to post questions to get some answers .... adding the code you have written would be a start ... Adding a list of requirements will not do ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would have a looming deadline for what seems to be a complex project for someone who is a rails/javascript newbie, however, this site (a free online version of his book) helped me immensely when I first started programming with rails, and it has some parts that highlight using ajax requests in rails which will probably be helpful for that part as well.

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Once you get on to the more complex ajax parts, try googling some of your questions.  Good luck.

Comment: +1 for the tutorial link ... not a rails man myself but like to learn by examples ..

Comment: I have completed that tutorial right through. My problem is that I alomost have to go backwards and make explicit the JQuery calls etc.